# Python and SSL -- EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, http, authentication, cookies, ssl

I'm trying to login to the web-site via Python. I have the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('ClientCookie-1.3.0')
import ClientCookie
sys.path.append('ClientForm-0.2.10')
import ClientForm

cookieJar = ClientCookie.CookieJar()

opener = ClientCookie.build_opener(ClientCookie.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
opener.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)")]
ClientCookie.install_opener(opener)
fp = ClientCookie.urlopen("login_page_url")
forms = ClientForm.ParseResponse(fp)
fp.close()

# print forms on this page
for form in forms: 
    print("***************************")
    print(form)

form = forms[2]
form["username"] = "some_username"
form["password"] = "some_password"
fp = ClientCookie.urlopen(form.click())
fp.close()
fp = ClientCookie.urlopen("some_url_for_authorized_users_only")
html = fp.read()
fp.close();
print(html.decode('utf-8'))
```

**Output**

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

What am I doing wrong? What does it mean? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem you have is caused by the obsolete version of OpenSSL.
Check the version by

```
 $ openssl version -a
```

and

```
 $ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
```

These may not be consistent. The first command shows the version your system use. If you see a different (possible older) version for second command, which means python doesn't refer to the latest openssl you installed.

In my case, first result was 0.9~ so I upgraded OpenSSL via homebrew, to 1.0.2k. Then I reinstalled python to enforce the newer version.

[howtoupgradessl](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401#.p7n5ijlvt) is a good reference to upgrade ssl if you use mac. In that case, you also might want to refer [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11/208481#208481) as well since newer osx have stronger security which you need to unlock.